# remove duplicate code by passing a method or something?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I have two methods exactly like each other but just in a line 
imagine :

```
    public void ApplyHorizontalScale(int x, int Y)
    {
        // Code 1
        forecast.Formula = Method1(X, Y);
        // Code 2
    }


    public void ApplyVerticalScale(int x, int Y)
    {
        // Code 1
        forecast.Formula = Method2("Foo");
        // Code 2
    }


    int Method1(int x , int y)
    {
        return x+y;
    }

    int Method2(string s)
    {
        return Foo.Length;
    }
```

The problem is Code 1 and Code 2 have been repeated twice!
how can I have something like :

```
public void ApplyScale(int x, int Y, WhichMethod)
{
        // Code 1
        forecast.Formula = WhichMethod();
        // Code 2
}
```

please notice that Method1 and Method2 have different signature and also one of them is accessing a private member.

Comment: i think you are doing it wrong.. think if you really need to have two methods that do the same thing but a line of code..

Comment: What is wrong with a parameter "bool useMethod1" and an oldfashioned "forecast.Formula = useMethod1 ? Method1(x,y) : Method2("Foo");"

Comment: well, I'm trying to find a better solution :-)

Comment: Eddiy, There are many methods. not just 2. moreover I don't want my code to be modified later if a new method shows up.

Comment: Why is your `Formula` a plain value? That is an awkward name for a *value*. Could you post some additional code to clarify what these methods are really doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ApplyVerticalScale and ApplyHorizontalScale are perfectly good methods - you don't need to combine them into one "God" ApplyScale public method.

You should refactor the internals of the method to call some private ApplyScale (or similar) method that contains Code1 and Code2 once, with each method passing whatever it needs to apply scale in that particular orientation.

Answer (score 3):

This is one way to do it

```
public void ApplyScale(int x, int Y, bool isHorizontal)
{
    // Code 1
    if(isHorizontal)
    {
       forecast.Formula = Method1(X, Y);
    }
    else
    {
       forecast.Formula = Method2("Foo");
    }
    // Code 2
}
```

You can also use `enum` instead of the `isHorizontal` flag

Comment: +1, I'd go for the enum though: it is more understandable and more extensible.

Comment: Yeah! I agree, but was bit lazy to write the extra 6 lines for enum implementation :)

Answer (score 1):

You have plenty of different options. Which one is most suitable depends on your scenario.

- Place Code 1 and code 2 in **separate functions**; this reduces the duplicate code to just two lines of duplicate code.
- Pass an enum/boolean **option parameter** to the function. Based on this parameter you can check whether you have to call `Method1` or `Method2`.
- Use an **abstract base class** and use concrete implementations to supply `Formula`.
- Pass around **delegates**.

Answer (score 1):

By introducing a 3rd method, you can refactor as follows:

```
public void ApplyHorizontalScale(int x, int Y) 
{ 
    DoWork(x,y, ()=>Method1(X,Y));
} 


public void ApplyVerticalScale(int x, int Y) 
{ 
    DoWork(x,y, ()=>Method2("Foo"));
} 

private void DoWork(int x, int y, Func<int> action)
{
     // Code 1
     forecast.Formula = action();
     // Code 2
}

int Method1(int x , int y) 
{ 
    return x+y; 
} 

int Method2(string s) 
{ 
    return Foo.Length; 
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the common thing is that your "Formula" property needs to get an `int` value.

In that case, something as simple as this would do:

```
public void ApplyScale(int x, int Y, int value)
{
    // ...
    forecast.Formula = value;
    // ...
}
```

And then call it with a different **value** each time:

```
ApplyScale(x, y, x + y);
ApplyScale(x, y, Foo.Length);
```

If you want to lazy calculate this value, you can do it like this:

```
public void ApplyScale(int x, int Y, Func<int> formula)
{
    // ...
    forecast.Formula = formula();
    // ...
}
```

And then call it with a different **lambda** each time:

```
ApplyScale(x, y, () => x + y);
ApplyScale(x, y, () => Foo.Length);
```

I don't see a real benefit in the latter approach, so I would simply pass the value to the method (unless there is something else behind your question, that I didn't understand).